I have a Bug on RN 0.74
When run in RN 0.73.7 all things are ok but RN 74 failed on Android with this message:
Error: Failed to create a new MMKV instance: React Native is not running on-device. MMKV can only be used when synchronous method invocations (JSI) are possible. If you are using a remote debugger (e.g. Chrome), switch to an on-device debugger (e.g. Flipper) instead.
Is the new version for RN 0.74 still a work in progress? so we can use the beta channel to test it out but I am not sure if it's production-ready or not any idea of this?

You need to create a custom storage class similar to how mmkv storage works. The issue comes with RN 0.74 and mmkv 2.12.2 which does not allow mmkv instance in development mode. The work around I got is provided below.
import { MMKV } from "react-native-mmkv";

type Listener = (key: string) => void;
   
export class MMKVFaker {
private data: { [key: string]: string | undefined } = {};
private listeners: Listener[] = [];

getString(key: string): string | undefined {
return this.data[key];
}

set(key: string, value: string): void {
this.data[key] = value;
this.notifyListeners(key);
}

delete(key: string): void {
delete this.data[key];
this.notifyListeners(key);
}

clearAll(): void {
this.data = {};
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => this.notifyListeners(key));
}

addOnValueChangedListener(listener: Listener): () => void {
this.listeners.push(listener);
return () => {
  const index = this.listeners.indexOf(listener);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.listeners.splice(index, 1);
  }
}}

    private notifyListeners(key: string): void {
    this.listeners.forEach(listener => listener(key));
    }
}

export const storage = __DEV__ ? new MMKVFaker() : new MMKV({ id: `unique-storage-id`});


I had the same issue in my expo react native app with mmkv version ^2.12.2, and solved it by commenting out the following fragment in MainApplication.kt:
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }

